# Unable to Parse Json via index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse JSON file but I'm facing some problems

```
{"prices": {"XRP/ETH": "0.0011228", "LTC/XRP": "187.7162", "BCH/INR": "53200.000", "LTC/BCH": "0.0729828", "LTC/BTC": "0.01567781", "LTC/ETH": "0.1948464", "XRP/BTC": "0.00006908", "BCH/ETH": "1.6930769", "XRP/INR": "32.000", "XRP/BCH": "0.0003879", "BCH/BTC": "0.22700587", "ETH/INR": "30500.000", "LTC/INR": "5280.000", "BTC/INR": "453000.000", "ETH/BTC": "0.07717977"}, "market": {"XRP/ETH": {"top_ask": "0.0010922 ETH", "top_bid": "0.0009030 ETH"}, "LTC/XRP": {"top_ask": "193.2886 XRP", "top_bid": "165.0000 XRP"}, "BCH/INR": {"top_ask": "56000.000 INR", "top_bid": "46100.000 INR"}, "LTC/BCH": {"top_ask": "0.1249458 BCH", "top_bid": "0.0942857 BCH"}, "LTC/BTC": {"top_ask": "0.01280000 BTC", "top_bid": "0.01147826 BTC"}, "LTC/ETH": {"top_ask": "0.1965870 ETH", "top_bid": "0.1600000 ETH"}, "XRP/BTC": {"top_ask": "0.00007111 BTC", "top_bid": "0.00006478 BTC"}, "BCH/ETH": {"top_ask": "1.9112628 ETH", "top_bid": "1.3969697 ETH"}, "XRP/INR": {"top_ask": "32.000 INR", "top_bid": "29.800 INR"}, "XRP/BCH": {"top_ask": "0.0006941 BCH", "top_bid": "0.0005321 BCH"}, "BCH/BTC": {"top_ask": "0.12444444 BTC", "top_bid": "0.10021739 BTC"}, "ETH/INR": {"top_ask": "33000.000 INR", "top_bid": "29300.000 INR"}, "LTC/INR": {"top_ask": "5760.000 INR", "top_bid": "5280.000 INR"}, "BTC/INR": {"top_ask": "460000.000 INR", "top_bid": "450000.000 INR"}, "ETH/BTC": {"top_ask": "0.07333333 BTC", "top_bid": "0.06369565 BTC"}}}
```

I'm trying to parse it in Javascript,but I receive an error undefined object,

My javascript Code:-

```
request(ticker, function (err, body) {
    var a = JSON.parse(body.body);
    var p= a.prices;
    console.log(p[0]);
    console.log(p.length);

});
```

I expect console.log to print out first iteration in the JSON that is "XRP/ETH", also I want to find the length of the array but I receive an undefined error

Comment: `p` is not an `array`, it is an `object`, you should use `Object.<entries, keys, values>` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Because `a.prices` is not an **array** (to be indexed by numeric keys), but an **object**:

```
{ "prices": {"XRP/ETH": "0.0011228", ... } }
            ^                            ^
```

Note the braces (`{ }`).

So, `a.prices[0]` is invalid, but `a.prices["XRP/ETH"]` is correct:

```js
var a = {"prices": {"XRP/ETH": "0.0011228" }}
console.log(a.prices["XRP/ETH"]);
```

To use it as an array, you can use `Object.entries(obj)` function which returns an array of pairs, which contain the keys and values of the input object:

```js
var a = {"prices": {"XRP/ETH": "0.0011228" }}
var p = Object.entries(a.prices);
console.log('Array:', p);
console.log('[0] key', p[0][0]);
console.log('[0] value', p[0][1]);
console.log('Length:', p.length);
```

Comment: It there a builtin function to convert it to array?, Also I want to find out total members in Prices,is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

As juzraai has stated, you can't access an object via index (structure[0]), you need to access it via key (structure["key"]), however it is possible to iterate over the contents of the object from a key:value perspective and only log the first iteration, like so;

```
    request(ticker, function (err, body) {
    var a = JSON.parse(body.body);
    var p= a.prices;
    var count = 0;
    for (var k in p){
       //Ensure key exists in dict
       if (p.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        if(count < 1){
        alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + target[k]);

    }
    count++;        
       }
    }   
    console.log(count);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Few observations :**

- Your JSON is already an object. Hence, no need to parse it again.
- `prices` is an object not an array. Hence instead of `p[0]` it should be `p["XRP/ETH"]`.
- As `p` is not an array hence `p.length` will not work. instead you can try `Object.keys(p).length`.

**Demo**

```js
var obj = {"prices": {"XRP/ETH": "0.0011228", "LTC/XRP": "187.7162", "BCH/INR": "53200.000", "LTC/BCH": "0.0729828", "LTC/BTC": "0.01567781", "LTC/ETH": "0.1948464", "XRP/BTC": "0.00006908", "BCH/ETH": "1.6930769", "XRP/INR": "32.000", "XRP/BCH": "0.0003879", "BCH/BTC": "0.22700587", "ETH/INR": "30500.000", "LTC/INR": "5280.000", "BTC/INR": "453000.000", "ETH/BTC": "0.07717977"}, "market": {"XRP/ETH": {"top_ask": "0.0010922 ETH", "top_bid": "0.0009030 ETH"}, "LTC/XRP": {"top_ask": "193.2886 XRP", "top_bid": "165.0000 XRP"}, "BCH/INR": {"top_ask": "56000.000 INR", "top_bid": "46100.000 INR"}, "LTC/BCH": {"top_ask": "0.1249458 BCH", "top_bid": "0.0942857 BCH"}, "LTC/BTC": {"top_ask": "0.01280000 BTC", "top_bid": "0.01147826 BTC"}, "LTC/ETH": {"top_ask": "0.1965870 ETH", "top_bid": "0.1600000 ETH"}, "XRP/BTC": {"top_ask": "0.00007111 BTC", "top_bid": "0.00006478 BTC"}, "BCH/ETH": {"top_ask": "1.9112628 ETH", "top_bid": "1.3969697 ETH"}, "XRP/INR": {"top_ask": "32.000 INR", "top_bid": "29.800 INR"}, "XRP/BCH": {"top_ask": "0.0006941 BCH", "top_bid": "0.0005321 BCH"}, "BCH/BTC": {"top_ask": "0.12444444 BTC", "top_bid": "0.10021739 BTC"}, "ETH/INR": {"top_ask": "33000.000 INR", "top_bid": "29300.000 INR"}, "LTC/INR": {"top_ask": "5760.000 INR", "top_bid": "5280.000 INR"}, "BTC/INR": {"top_ask": "460000.000 INR", "top_bid": "450000.000 INR"}, "ETH/BTC": {"top_ask": "0.07333333 BTC", "top_bid": "0.06369565 BTC"}}};

var p = obj.prices;

console.log(p["XRP/ETH"]);
console.log(Object.keys(p).length);
```